# Azure Iot hub client communication with multiple devices

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I have a node.js server application that communicates with Iot devices using Azure IoT Hub service.

When I examine the sample code [sample code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node/blob/master/service/samples/send_c2d_message.js) from Azure repository about cloud to device message. I see that one client was created. If there are multiple devices and multiple messages to be sent to multiple devices, **is it okay to create multiple Iot hub clients, or should I stick to one client solution. What could be the cons and pros of two approach?**

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Azure IoT Hub feature for your scenario such as a [Schedule and broadcast jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-node-node-schedule-jobs). This feature enables a cloud back-end to schedule and update millions of devices based on your needs.